# Auto-apply a role to new phpBB user with password or code

Tags: forum, registration, phpbb

Is there a way, with phpBB to have a new user enter a password which would automatically move them into a specific role? I'd like to be able to allow certain people to sign up and automatically have access to certain forums, without having to wait to be approved.

If not, would someone point me in the right direction on how to set this up? I'm not as fluent in PHP as I am in C# and javascript, but if I got the general idea of where to make the changes, I could probably whip something up.

I pictured an "Authentication ID" field, where I could provide a code in advance... a guid or something. When they registered, it'd automatically move them from the new user role to a specific one.

Comment: How would you filter your users (you said 'certain users')? If there is a fixed filter, a database trigger could work just fine.

Comment: I pictured an "Authentication ID" field, where I could provide a code in advance... a guid or something. When they registered, it'd automatically move them from the new user role to a specific one. (added to description)